# How to prevent Scroll Box from consuming touch event in Unreal?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am working on a UI system for a mobile game in Unreal. I have functionality already in place that basically reads in if the player has swiped by basically getting the player's initial touch location and then checking if the player moves their finger a certain pixel distance and then it changes between pages.

I am trying to add a scroll box to the page as I find that not all of my content will fit on the screen. However, now that I have added it to my Widget, my swiping function no longer works. I am assuming this is because the scroll box is consuming the touch event. Is there a way to make it so that the scrolling does not consume the input event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem but unfortunately, I couldn't find how to continue to read touch events.

As a workaround, I created my own scrollbox, so that I could read the finger location while I'm scrolling.

Comment: As I could tell. There is no way to do this. Your answer seems like the logical thing to do.

Comment: Care to share your solution?!